# Pages on server can be accessed but server cant connect to internet?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

I have a  virtualbox server running ubuntu 12.04 on a windows 7 host machine. The machine is set up to have both a NAT and a bridged adapter.

When I access the server from other machines (port forwarding to the host machine and then to the server through VBox) I am shown the correct pages and can navigate the subdirectories.

However, I recently tried to run a sudo apt-get and was unable to connect to "us.archive.ubuntu.com" or any other site. Additionally, I only seem to be able to ping machines on the local network.

I am very new to networking; can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: probably dns or your gateway

Comment: You need to troubleshoot. Can you ping out by IP address? (Your question seems to imply you can't, but it's hard to be sure.) Where do `traceroute`'s stop? What does your default route point to? And so on.

Comment: David - I can ping machines on the local network by IP but anything else can't be reached as far as i can tell. I can't really do a traceroute right now, no apt-get... I suppose it would show my greenness to ask what you mean by default route?

Comment: The default route tells the OS where to send packets whose destination is not covered by a more specific route. Do a `route -n` and look for the entry for destination `0.0.0.0`. Make sure the "Gateway" is the router that you handles your connection to the Internet and make sure it's reachable (with `ping`).

Comment: okay so I've checked with route n and I think I have the wrong address there. how would i change it?

Answer (score 0):

You've verified connectivity via IP address. Next thing to check is your DNS. Can you ping 8.8.8.8, a DNS server that belongs to google? If so, then your routing and NAT is all set, you just probably didn't configure DNS client settings on the Ubuntu machine. Set it to use proper DNS servers - probably the same ones that your Windows 7 host machine is using.

Comment: Didn't have any luck pinging it, I kept getting "host unreachable"

Answer (score 0):

Okay lads I figured it out. I just had the dns and gateway settings wrong. I realize it's probably a dumb mistake but thank you to those who put me on the right track.

All I had to do was use nm-connection-editor to set the gateway and DNS server addresses on the guest machine to the same as on the host machine.

And now I'm off to save the machine state... several thousand times...